# How to create a Matrix like table

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie in using VBA in excel.

I have 2 worksheets, "Source" and "Matrix". In the Source sheet, I have columns A and B. I want to transpose column A vertically and B horizontally to the other worksheet "Matrix". Then, in their intersection, mark that cell 1 if there's a match from Source.

This is how the Source Worksheet looks like:

[image: image1]

This is how I am envisioning the expected result will look like in the Matrix Worksheet:

[image: image2]

Is this possible through Excel VBA?

I appreciate any help.. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: VLookup and IF functions will help you out here. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: I tried Vlookup and IF functions but it still lacks. I just found out that I can use Pivot to create the matrix that I'm looking for. :)